# Can the electric polarisation lead to a similar effect like the Anomalous Hall Effect

Tags: electromagnetism, polarization

The magnetisation of a material leads to an Anomalous Hall Effect in a material. Is there a similar effect that arises from the electric Polarisation of a material?